# Abrir item clicado da ListView em uma nova activity

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um projeto, porém não estou conseguindo abrir o item da `listView`. Já estou inserindo e editando, mas só consigo abrir o último item criado. Por exemplo, tenho 10 itens na lista, mas somente o ultimo que eu criar, independente do qual eu clique, abre sempre o mesmo. Se eu excluo o último criado, somente o anterior a ele abre.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para abrir o item clicado com seu conteúdo, pois somente quando clico é que posso apagar ou editar. O que preciso implementar é o `listaUma` no final do `DAOideia`.

ListaIdeia.class

```
public class ListaIdeia extends ActionBarActivity{

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_ideia);

        this.listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<Ideia> lista = new DAOIdeia(this).buscar();
        IdeiaAdapter ideiaAdapter = new IdeiaAdapter(this,lista);
        this.listView.setAdapter(ideiaAdapter);


        this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int p, long id) {


                if(p < 200) {
                    Intent segundaActivity = new Intent(ListaIdeia.this, DetalhesIdeia.class);
                    startActivity(segundaActivity);

                }
            }
        });

DAOIdeia.class 

public class DAOIdeia {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DAOIdeia(Context context){
        this.db = new SQLiteCore(context).getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insert(Ideia ideia){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("nome",ideia.getNome());
        valores.put("descricao",ideia.getDescricao());

        this.db.insert("ideia",null,valores);
    }

    public void update(Ideia ideia){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("nome",ideia.getNome());
        valores.put("descricao",ideia.getDescricao());

        this.db.update("ideia",valores,"_id = ?",new String[]{""+ideia.get_id()});
    }

    public void delete(Ideia ideia){
        this.db.delete("ideia","_id = ?",new String[]{""+ideia.get_id()});
    }

    public ArrayList<Ideia> buscar(){
        ArrayList<Ideia> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","nome","descricao"};
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query("ideia",colunas,null,null,null,null,"nome DESC");

        if (cursor.getCount() >0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                Ideia ideia = new Ideia();
                ideia.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                ideia.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
                ideia.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));
                lista.add(ideia);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    public ArrayList<Ideia> listaUma(){
        ArrayList<Ideia> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","nome","descricao"};
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query("ideia",colunas,null,null,null,null,"nome DESC");

        if (cursor.getCount() >0) {


            Ideia ideia = new Ideia();
            ideia.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
            ideia.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            ideia.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));
            lista.add(ideia);

        }
        return lista;
    }
```

---

Parte que cria o `ArrayList`

```
public class DetalhesIdeia extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_ideia);

        this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<Ideia> lista = new DAOIdeia(this).listaUma();
        IdeiaAdapterEdit IdeiaAdapterEdit = new IdeiaAdapterEdit(this, lista);
        this.listView.setAdapter(IdeiaAdapterEdit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua condição ali do `if(p < 200)`. O que quer dizer?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema você precisa criar uma condição para reconhecer o item que foi clicado. Veja abaixo como seria:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

            /* o position representa a posição que o usuário clicou*/

            switch (position){
                // case clicar na posição 0, significa que e o primeiro item
                case 0:
                    // faça algo referente ao item 1 a este item aqui dentro

                    break;
                // case clicar na posição 1, significa que e o segundo item
                case 1:
                    // faça algo referente ao item 2 a este item aqui dentro

                    break;
                // case clicar na posição 2, significa que e o terceiro item
                case 2:
                    // faça algo referente ao item 3 a este item aqui dentro

                    break;
                // assim por diante ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Não tem uma forma melhor de se fazer isso? visto que uma lista pode ter centenas de itens... Não programo em android, mas creio que desta forma esteja "errada"